# When I count box which are checked, it counts plus one box

Tags: javascript, checkbox, frontend

My web-app is about forecasting on sports games.
My page shows all the matches and the points you can get out of each outcome from a match (Madrid = 12 points VS Barcelone = 15 points).
So a user check a box from a match and select for him the right outcome.
I would like each time the user check a box, to show him the number of boxes he checked.

Here is my Javascript to count the box checked :

```
    const updateCount = function() {
      var x = document.querySelectorAll(".square:checked").length;
      document.querySelector(".plus").innerHTML = x;
    };
```

Here is the HTML where the number of box checked will be displayed

```
<div class=" d-flex pt-2">
            <h3 class="typos">Matchs pronostiqués</h3>
            <h3 class="typos pts" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 5px;"><%= current_user.forecasts.where(confirmed: true, season_id: Season.last.id).count %>/50</h3>
            <span class="plus"></span>
          </div>
```

Here is my Javascript in order to know which game the user forecasted and which outcome he selected :

```
const selectOutcome = () => {
  const selects = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
  selects.forEach((outcome)=>{
    outcome.addEventListener("click",(event) => {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
      const result = event.currentTarget.dataset.outcome;
      console.log(result);
      const id = event.currentTarget.parentNode.dataset.id;
      console.log(id);
      const box = event.currentTarget.checked;
      console.log(box);
      const url = 'store_outcome?result='+result+'&match='+id+'&box='+box
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      });
    });
  });
}

const validePanier = () => {
  const panier = document.getElementById('panier');
  panier.addEventListener("click", (event) =>{
    console.log("click")
    const player = document.getElementById('season_player').value;
    fetch('confirm_pending?player='+player)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    });
  })
}
```

Here is my HTML, for each match I have in my database, a match is going to appear in front in this way.

```
    <% @matches.each do |match| %>
          <% if Time.parse(match.kick_off) > Time.now && current_user.forecasts.find_by(match_id: match.id, confirmed: true).nil? && match.points_home.present? %>
          <% if match.sport == "football" %>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
          <h4 class="typopo"><%= match.league %></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
          <h3 class="tit"><%= DateTime.parse(match.kick_off).to_date%></h3><h3 class="typopo pl-2">-</h3>
          <h3 class="typopo pl-2"><%= match.kick_off.to_s.gsub("T", " ").split[1].gsub("+", " ").split[0]%></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around mb-4 mt-4" data-id="<%= match.id %>">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center col-4">
            <div class="row">
              <h3 class="typopo"><%= image_tag "#{match.team_home_logo_url}", width: 50 %></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-align-center">
              <h3 class="tit"><%= match.team_home %></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <p class="typopo text-center">VS</p>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center col-4">
              <div class="displaysquares" data-id="<%= match.id %>">
                <input type="checkbox" class="square" onclick="updateCount()" data-outcome="1"></input>
                <input type="checkbox" class="square" onclick="updateCount()" data-outcome="NULL"></input>
                <input type="checkbox" class="square" onclick="updateCount()" data-outcome="2"></input>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

There is a data-id. The purpose is when a user check a box, I can get the id of the match, in order to create the right forecast for the right game.

Comment: Hello, the problem is with this data-id I can't get the id of the match and then create a forecast.

Comment: You do not have any mentioning of data-id in your question at all - what is the relevance?

Comment: It was in the HTML code ``` data-id="<%= match.id %>"``` The purpose is when a user check a box it's in relation with the outcome of a special game ("1" - "NULL" - "2"). So I get the outcome he choose for the game (which has an idea, I'm getting from the data-id).

Comment: Hope it's more clear now

Comment: It is not clear at all. Please click edit, then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and then paste RENDERED HTML that is RELEVANT to the question. If you have more than one match, paste 2 or 3 matches. Also there is NOTHING with class="pts" in the html you posted.

Comment: But it's ruby on rails, like if I put @matches, it means there are many matches ? For the class, I changed it, it's class="plus", sorry

Comment: Your question is not related to ruby at all. I do not know ruby, I can only guess you have a loop. Please post RENDERED HTML - you can even remove the ruby tag. It is an HTML+JavaScript issue and nothing else

Comment: Is the plus inside ALL entries or only ONCE on the page?

Comment: I meant ruby because you didn't understand that my front will display many matches thanks to the ruby tag. No the plus is only present once.

Comment: So each match will be displayed as you can see in the second part of my HTML part. It means, each match will have checkboxes in order for the user to select the outcome he wants.

Comment: Yes I did understand when you posted the `<% @matches.each do |match| %>` which is when I posted my example with two matches. HOWEVER your HTML is not complete.
SO I ASK YOU: Please post the RENDERED HTML of TWO or THREE matches WITHOUT RUBY and WITH the PLUS field visible in VALID HTML instead of the ruby you have now.

Comment: Can you see my example now - does it do what you want it to do? I have two matches. I think you MIGHT want the VALUE of a RADIO instead of the COUNT of checked boxes

Comment: I found the answer, I used the code below, thank you.

Comment: I added a radio version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delegate instead of having inline event handlers

Here I COUNT the checkboxes - why do you not want the VALUE of a checked RADIO?

Note I wrapped all matches in `<div id="matches">...</div>`

```js
document.getElementById("matches").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("square")) {
    const parent = tgt.closest(".displaysquares");
    var x = parent.querySelectorAll(".square:checked").length;
    document.querySelector(".plus").innerHTML += parent.dataset.id + ": " + x +"<br/>" ;
  }
})
```

```html
<span class="plus"></span>
<div id="matches">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h4 class="typopo">League 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h3 class="tit">
      Some date
    </h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">-</h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">Some string</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around mb-4 mt-4" data-id="MATCH 1">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="typopo">TEAM LOGO </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-align-center">
        <h3 class="tit">Some other team string</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <p class="typopo text-center">VS</p>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center col-4">
        <div class="displaysquares" data-id="MATCH 1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="square" data-outcome="1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="square" data-outcome="NULL">
          <input type="checkbox" class="square" data-outcome="2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h4 class="typopo">League 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h3 class="tit">
      Some date
    </h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">-</h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">Some string</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around mb-4 mt-4" data-id="MATCH 2">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="typopo">TEAM LOGO </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-align-center">
        <h3 class="tit">Some other team string</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <p class="typopo text-center">VS</p>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center col-4">
        <div class="displaysquares" data-id="MATCH 2">
          <input type="checkbox" class="square" data-outcome="1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="square" data-outcome="NULL">
          <input type="checkbox" class="square" data-outcome="2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Radios instead

```js
const matches = document.getElementById("matches")
matches.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("square")) {
    var x = [...matches.querySelectorAll(".square:checked")].map(chk => chk.closest(".displaysquares").dataset.id + ": "+chk.dataset.outcome)
    document.querySelector(".plus").innerHTML = x.join("<br/>");
  }
})
```

```html
<span class="plus"></span>
<div id="matches">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h4 class="typopo">League 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h3 class="tit">
      Some date
    </h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">-</h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">Some string</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around mb-4 mt-4" data-id="MATCH 1">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="typopo">TEAM LOGO </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-align-center">
        <h3 class="tit">Some other team string</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <p class="typopo text-center">VS</p>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center col-4">
        <div class="displaysquares" data-id="MATCH 1">
          <input type="radio" name="outcome1" class="square" data-outcome="1">
          <input type="radio" name="outcome1" class="square" data-outcome="NULL">
          <input type="radio" name="outcome1" class="square" data-outcome="2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h4 class="typopo">League 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 mt-2">
    <h3 class="tit">
      Some date
    </h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">-</h3>
    <h3 class="typopo pl-2">Some string</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around mb-4 mt-4" data-id="MATCH 2">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="typopo">TEAM LOGO </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-align-center">
        <h3 class="tit">Some other team string</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <p class="typopo text-center">VS</p>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center col-4">
        <div class="displaysquares" data-id="MATCH 2">
          <input type="radio" name="outcome2" class="square" data-outcome="1">
          <input type="radio" name="outcome2" class="square" data-outcome="NULL">
          <input type="radio" name="outcome2" class="square" data-outcome="2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried unfortunately it counts only for the first line of boxes, when I check the boxes beneath (next match), it doesn't take it into account. I'm gonna edit my HTML code in order to be more clear.

Comment: I changed in your first version "parent" by "document" and it works fine. Thank you